# Who are the big names in the gaming community?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

### Who are the influential people in the online gaming community?

People with popular:

- Websites
- Podcasts
- Blogs
- Game developers
- Other?

Who can we reach out to about our new site? Please note why they're influential and how they can be reached.  Bonus points if you know the person.

(one name per answer please)

Comment: Should this include popular games, where their name is distinctly associated with the game? This is usually indie developers, e.g., Jared Sorensen (hi there!) of *Freemarket* fame (among other games).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Definitely.  The questions on this site already have me interested in *Freemarket*

Answer (score 2):

Just off the top of my head, and in no particular order:

[Vincent Baker](http://www.lumpley.com/), administrator of The Forge and author of *Dogs in the Vineyard*, *In A Wicked Age*, *Apocalypse World*, and others. He's pretty active on his own site and people seem to come to his "place" disproportionately, so anyone's guess whether he'd have time and inclination for this site.

Fred Hicks is a major force behind Evil Hat and their games, and has a significant online presence. He'd probably be interested in SE if he's not already lurking.

Johnn Four writes/edits [Roleplaying Tips](http://www.roleplayingtips.com/index.php), which is a big deal.

Berin Kinsman is [the big uncle bear](http://unclebear.com/) of RPG blogging. He may be interested, but not have the time. Worth making him aware of it though, as he seems to believe in community-building. (He kicked off the Ning RPG social network before Ning went sideways.)

Chatty DM is a big, vocal presence online and always has a positive view. Also big on community building, he cofounded the RPG Bloggers Network.

[Dave Chalker](http://davechalker.wordpress.com/) is a luminary of blogging as cofounder of Critical Hits.

The crew at [Gnome Stew](http://www.gnomestew.com/), of which there are many, run an influential site. I bet some of them would be interested in hanging out here, if they're not already.

Johnathan Jacobs of [The Core Mechanic](http://www.thecoremechanic.com/) is the force behind the [Open Game Table blog anthologies](http://stores.lulu.com/open_game_table), as well as a principle mover of [Nevermet Press](http://www.nevermetpress.com/).

[Wyatt Salazar/Dennis N. Santana](http://wyattsalazar.wordpress.com/) is a vocal blogger who has a lot of name recognition and writes insightful stuff.

[Russell "Morrus" Morrissey](http://www.enworld.org/forum/members/morrus.html) is the owner and operator of ENWorld.

[Brad Murray](http://www.vsca.ca/halfjack/) is the primary author of Diaspora, and is particularly active online.

Comment: Is Russel Morrissey our very own [rmorrisey](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/188/rmorrisey)?

Comment: It's possible, but I can't see definite connection from a brief lookabout.

Comment: I'm trying to contact a lot of these groups to let them know about the site.  Can you come up with a way to contact the guys at Gnome Stew?  I can't find any way to contact them, besides comments on random posts.

Comment: @C. Ross Martin Rayla is the "Head Gnome" and is martin(AT)gnomestew(DOT)com. If you sent an email to him humbly asking him to pass on the invitation to the rest of the gnomes, that might do it.

Answer (score 2):

Tycho (Jerry Holkins) and Gabe (Mike Krahulik) of [Penny Arcade](http://www.penny-arcade.com/) both play D&D which has been featured several times in their [comic](http://www.penny-arcade.com/archive/?q=d%26d). They have also done a series of the [WOTC D&D podcasts](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/rsspodcast.xml). They also host [Penny Arcade Expo (PAX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_Arcade_Expo), a gamer festival for console, computer, and tabletop gaming.

Comment: Definitely **BIG** names in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Johnathan Drain and his [d20 source](http://www.d20source.com/) blog has a number of good articles.  I've spoken with him a bunch in the past about various articles and D&D related material.  He has a sizable following and a mention there would get some traffic here.  I'll see about dropping him a line to check out the site.

Comment: Just got a mail from Johnathan, he said he'll plug the site in the near future.

Comment: Excellent, keep us posted!

Answer (score 0):

Ron Edwards is one of the cofounders of [The Forge](http://www.indie-rpgs.com/forge/index.php), and the author of indie games like *Sorcerer*, *Trollbabe*, *Elfs*, *Spione*, and *S/lay w/Me*. He's a vocal proponent of creator-owned game publishing, RPG theory, and game design that takes nothing for granted. He's extremely knowledgeable about the history of RPGs, game mechanics, and many specific RPGs (indie or otherwise).

You (or I) can send him a private message on The Forge. He's undoubtedly too busy for this site, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

I want my bonus points for knowing him. ;)

Comment: +50xp for knowing him. See if he wouldn't mind stopping by or giving us a shout out.

Comment: did you ever make contact?

Comment: Oops! I did just now.